# How to calculate how many pair of numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

i'm currently in this assignment that bother me how to calculate how many pairs of number within an array

this is what i've been tried before

```
 function pairNumber (n,ar)
  let numberOfPairs=0
    for(let i =0;i<ar.length;i++){
        for(let j =1;j<ar.length;j++){
            if (ar[i] == ar[j]){
                          console.log([ar[i], ar[j]], '<< ini isinya')
                          console.log(ar[i+1], ar[j+1])

                numberOfPairs++
                ar.splice(i,1)
                ar.splice(j,1)
            }
        }
    }

    if(n%3 == 0){
      numberOfPairs -= 1
      return numberOfPairs
    } else {
      return numberOfPairs
    }
}

console.log(sockMerchant(9,[10,20,20,10,10,30,50,10,20]))
console.log(sockMerchant(10,[1,1,3,1,2,1,3,3,3,3]))
```

but unfortunately, the return will always be

```
4
4
```

the correct answer should be

```
3
4
```

for both cases can someone please do help me what I've been missing? thanks you!

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: do  not mutate array while looping over it, also what is use of `n` ?

Answer (score 1):

I just do the sort for array first then you just need loop the array 1 time. It's better to control your code

```
function pairNumber (n,ar){
        let numberOfPairs=0
        let i = 0
        let j = 1

        ar.sort()
         for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
             if(ar[i] == ar[i++]){
                 numberOfPairs++
                 i+=1
             }
         }
         return numberOfPairs
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a simple assignment, I am not going to explain in detail. The issue seems to be in the loop variable initialization.
Hint: `j=i+1`

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the quadratic approach with O(n<sup>2</sup>), you could take an object and count the occurences.

At the end return the sum by counting only the floored half values.

```js
function pairNumber(n, array) {
    var numberOfPairs = 0,
        counts = {};
  
    for (let v of array) {
        if (!counts[v]) counts[v] = 0;
        ++counts[v];
    }

    for (let count of Object.values(counts)) numberOfPairs += count >> 1;

    return numberOfPairs;
}

console.log(pairNumber(9, [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]))
console.log(pairNumber(10, [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]))
```